# Graphics.DrawRectangle not working in control events

Tags: vb.net, events, graphics, enter, drawrectangle

First of all thank you for taking the time out of your busy schedule to assist me.

I am developing a project (Win Application) with a Form and 3 textboxes (TextBox1, TextBox2 and TextBox3).

I need draw a rectangle around the textbox when focused this.

The code is:

```
Private Sub TextBox123_Enter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter, TextBox3.Enter
    Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim r As Rectangle = sender.Bounds
        r.Inflate(4, 4)
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, r)
    End Using
End Sub
```

The problem is the following:

- The first time the textbox1 gains focus rectangle is not drawn.
- The first time the textbox2 gains focus rectangle is not drawn.

Why not the rectangle is drawn when the first two events enter are fired?

Comment: What do you mean *The first time the...*. When form loads?

Comment: Yes. When the form is loaded, the rectangle is not drawn (TextBox123.Enter event fires but DrawRectangle has no effect). Also when the first focus is changed, the rectangle is not drawn (when the focus is changed from TextBox1 to TextBox2)

Comment: It is drawn, but is immediately overpainted when the textbox repaints itself.  The standard hazard of using CreateGraphics(), using it is wrong 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing with `CreateGraphics` is almost always not the correct approach.  If you notice also, when you move from one box to another, the old rectangle is not being erased.  You need to use the `Form_Paint` event to get it to work right.  Or...perhaps simpler would be to create a UserControls which is 1-2 pixels larger than a child TextBox and set the backcolor of the UserControl canvas, draw your rectangle when the control gets the focus.

For form paint:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private HotControl As Control
```

If you are only going to do TextBoxes, you can declare it `As TextBox`.  This way it allows you to do the same for other control types.  Set/clear the tracker:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Enter,
           TextBox2.Enter, TextBox1.Enter
    HotControl = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave,
           TextBox2.Leave, TextBox3.Leave
    HotControl = Nothing
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

The `Me.Invalidate` tells the form to redraw itself, which happens in Paint:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    If HotControl IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim r As Rectangle = HotControl.Bounds
        r.Inflate(4, 4)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, r)
    End If

End Sub
```

You should also turn on Option Strict.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your code is very good!
Your explanations were very clear and understandable!
The problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `click event` handler

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        Dim rectangle As New Rectangle(TextBox1.Location.X - 1, _
            TextBox1.Location.Y - 1, _
            TextBox1.Size.Width + 1, _
            TextBox1.Size.Height + 1)
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rectangle)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the rectangle is not drawn to open the form and not drawn when changing focus with TAB key. 
I do not understand why not draw the rectangle the first two times it changes the focus